# RadGridView Delete event WPF

Tags: wpf, telerik

Is there some property that modifies the behavior of what key fire the deleteing and deleted events in the RadGridView.

It might be a bug, but my grid stopped firing this event suddenly. It used to work a few days back when I developed it. Now, that I added some more events and functionality to the screen it stopped working. One of my coworkers has the same issue with one of his screens.

Is it just me, or this components are pretty much filled with bugs. They also break with each update I make.

Comment: I've just run into this same problem.  When I change my RadGridView's ItemsSource binding, I can no longer delete rows ( The Deleting event never fires, and I have set CanUserDeleteRows = "true").  

If I simply go into edit mode on a cell, then cancel edit mode, however, I can now delete rows on the grid.  Did you see this same behavior? 

Very strange...still experimenting/researching.

Answer (score 2):

If you will set **CanUserDeleteRows** to false on the grid user will not be able to delete rows anymore.

There is also **Deleting** event on the grid where you can cancel pending delete request.

Additionally if you are using **PreviewKeyDown** event and setting e.Handled = true for delete key grid will not delete row.

Comment: PSA: Be sure to set `e.Cancel = true` rather than `e.Handled = true`.